# Chrome Vue devtools open in editor not working with WebStorm

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, devtools

In Chrome Vue devtools not working button "open in editor" with WebStorm IDE on the Macbook Air M1.

But it works fine in VS Code!

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains replied me:

this is a problem with binaries compatibility - looks as if chrome vue-devtools are built for Intel architecture, whereas WebStorm is built for Apple Silicon. You can try downloading the x86_64 version
.

but  x86_64  slowly  work  in m1